# Unintended endless While loop - why?

Tags: perl

I have an array of numeric values that's sorted. I also have a minimum and maximum value and want to remove any values from the array that are smaller than the minimum or bigger than the maximum value. I am getting an endless loop when my minimum value is smaller than the value of the first array element. Here's a minimal example of the code in question:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ( 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 );
my $min_wert = 1;
my $max_wert = 13;

while ( $array[0] < $min_wert ) {
    shift @array;
}
while ( $array[-1] > $max_wert ) {
    pop @array;
}

print join( ' ', @array );
print "\n";
```

The problem is, this version works flawlessly, outputting

```
5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
```

The first while is not entered in this case.

Dropping the same test case into my production code, I'm getting the following error message on the line with the shift-statement:

> Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at
>   line 1130.

I then introduced a counter to try to figure out why the while-loop is even entered, and that completely removes the problem instead of giving me the opportunity for further diagnostics.

```
    @werte_liste = sort {$a <=> $b} @werte_liste; 
    print join( ' ', @werte_liste );
    print "\n";
    print "Start: $start_index - Stop: $stop_index\n"

    while ( $werte_liste[0] < $start_index ) {
        print "In while-loop- why?\n";
        shift @werte_liste;
    }
    while ( $werte_liste[-1] > $stop_index ) {
        pop @werte_liste;
    }
```

why do I enter that first while loop in this case? And second, is there a better solution to my specific problem (I'm not talking lots of values here, so readability of code is more important than efficiency).

Comment: Please edit the relevant output from your production script into the question.

Comment: The print statement within your first `while` loop would be more useful if it were: `print "In shift while loop: \$start_index=($start_index), \$werte_liste[0]=($werte_liste[0]), size of \@werte_liste=(", scalar(@werte_liste), ").\n";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it works with your testcase but doesn't in your production code, but here's my guess:

Your array becomes empty. `$array[0] < $min_wert` is true if `$array[0]` is `undef` (which happens if the array is empty), and `$min_wert > 0`.

`undef` is basically treated as a `0` in numerical comparisons (it emits a warning).

You can check that the array still has elements with this:

```
while ( @array and $array[0] < $min_wert ) {
```

The other `while` loop probably has the same problem.

Comment: I guess my problem was that in the print-statement before the loop, my array did not show as empty, and I still got that error. Adding that test for emptiness solves that nevertheless, and it gets me the correct results for the following test cases, where in one of those the array is indeed empty going in. I guess I was just stumped because of getting the error on a non-empty array.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when `@werte_liste` is empty?

For one, `$werte_liste[0]` will be undefined, and the expression `$werte_liste[0] < $start_index` will generate the `Use of uninitialized value in numerlic lt ...` warnings.

For another, `$werte_liste[0]` will evaluate to 0 for the `<` comparison. If `$start_index` is positive, then `$werte_liste[0] < $start_index` is true.

Finally, `shift @werte_liste` will have no effect on `@werte_liste`, `@werte_liste` will remain empty, and your `while ...` expression will repeat indefinitely.